# No suffix added when recompiling kernel with debian/rules binary

Tags: 20.04, kernel, compiling

I am compiling 5.15.0-48 from git://kernel.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-focal.git branch origin/hwe-5.15.0-next, modifying a few configs (tickless kernel) and generating the .deb files with devscripts.

I edit the changelog file with `debchange` then recompile with `LANG=C fakeroot debian/rules binary`

The first time it added the +nohz suffix that I added in the changelog. However when I recompile the suffix is not there anymore. What could I possibly be doing wrong?

"suffix not there" meaning that the .deb files are not being generated with the suffix anymore

Answer (score 0):

You have to run debchange AFTER you fun `debian/rules clean` since this command will rewrite all the configuration files.